# add multiple rows on a column php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, row

I would like to make a shop online for a school project but we I like to use mysql and I know only the bases of this program. So I want to insert multiple row(items) in a single column and acces them.
How can I do this?
I want the table to look something like this.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmPXE.png)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056).  Also you should google about `dynamic unpivot in mysql` and try to implement it. In case you are not able to implement it, give us your sample data in tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed our attached image in which there are 3 columns Id,name & items where items column having multiple values.

So,with assumption you require similar structure i am providing my answer.

1) According to best practice to have multiple values in a column for single row is wrong. You have to follow normalization in this case. so, you have to break the table in 2 part.
2)In worst case you have to use same structure so in this case you can use varchar column for items where you can keep comma separated multiple values.